# How do I prevent the console (application file) from closing itself immediately after running in windows?

Tags: c

After I compile my program and run the executable, it closes instantaneously. I barely see my output.  How do I prevent this?

Comment: Try running from a command line.

Comment: Y>ou could either run the exe from a console window or add ``system("pause")`` the end. Not trying to be rude but Google would have told you the same...

Comment: Use `getchar();` to pause program execution.

Answer (score 24):

The following two lines will print the message "Press ENTER key to Continue" and then pause execution waiting for the enter key. I hope this helps.

```
printf("Press ENTER key to Continue\n");  
getchar();
```

Comment: I used two different versions of Windows 10 on two different PCs and adding `getchar()` did not do anything about this problem.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is quite common when starting to learn C/C++..

the reason is that console applications once finisher return from their main method, the associated console window automatically closes. This behavior has nothing to do with what your app does or not, or if the app is working well or not.

To "correct" this simple add a pause just before the return statement in the main method

## Example:

```
....
   system("pause");  
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: it works only for Windows

Comment: I am using Windows 10 x64 and adding `system ("pause")` did not help, instead it raised an implicit declaration warning error. I searched and I added <stdlib.h> now it says: `sh: pause: command not found.`

Answer (score 4):

- Try to run it natively through the cmd.

Let's say that your file is in `C:\file.exe`
Open the cmd, type `cd C:\` and then type `file.exe`

- Try to add `system("pause");` to your program to keep it opened.

like below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello world!");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system("pause")` isn't cross platform.

Comment: Only option 1 worked for me with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
int main()
{

   // your code

   system("pause"); // this will stop the pause 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using Windows 10 x64 and adding system ("pause") did not help, instead it raised an implicit declaration warning error.