# How to fix the problem of opening an .exe file which flashes(closes instantly after the program's end)?

Tags: c, exe, codeblocks

I've been coding for a while with codeblocks and I've coded some C programs. In my project folder of my programs there is the .exe file that I used to click on and get its console output. But today when I click on them and when the program ends it closes instantly without asking me to press a key to quit the program.

The solutions for this problem I've found are to add "system("pause")" and other stuff like that or to compile it directly on the cmd or on codeblocks(and they don't fix the problem as well). But I would like to know how I could be able to open the .exe files like back then.

Comment: When you are coding for Rome then execute like a Roman.  Run non-GUI apps from the console.  You certainly can make it work either way, but that requires an [OS call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256385/17034).

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like that at the end of your program?

```
    scanf("%c",waitVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
printf("Press ENTER key to Continue\n");  
getchar();
```

at the end of your code. The same question can be found here:
[how to prevent c program from closing immediately after running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188896/how-to-prevent-a-c-program-from-closing-immediately-after-running/36188994)